# How to join @xml.nodes to table column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to query an XML file, and also join to an existing table column.  The XML part works okay in isolation, but breaks when I attempt the join.  I know the syntax is wrong somewhere.  Could anyone please advise how to get the ID column of the XML data to link to the ID column in `MyTable`?

```
SELECT
    CAST(u.n.value('@ID', 'int') AS int),
    CAST(u.n.value('@userId', 'int') AS int),
    CAST(u.n.value('@roleId', 'int') AS int),
    ah.DateCol
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/appliedprofiles/ah') AS u (n) CROSS APPLY
    [MyTable] ah ON CAST(u.n.value('@ID', 'int') AS int) = ah.ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. The [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator do not support `ON` clause.
You need to use proper join clause to do that.

This should work:

```
SELECT
    CAST(u.n.value('@ID', 'int') AS int),
    CAST(u.n.value('@userId', 'int') AS int),
    CAST(u.n.value('@roleId', 'int') AS int),
    ah.DateCol
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/appliedprofiles/ah') AS u (n) INNER JOIN
    [MyTable] ah ON CAST(u.n.value('@ID', 'int') AS int) = ah.ID
```